# RecyclerView items go off screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a RecyclerView with elements in it, I want the delete button for the element to be on the right side.
When I test it on an emulator or look at the look of it in Android Studio, it looks fine, but when I launch the application on a real device, the button goes beyond the borders of the screen.
My question is how to set the right alignment for button, and do so the text does not overlapping the button, but ends with an ellipsis or wraps on the next line.

On the emulator and in Android Studio:
[On emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kIhPT.png)
[In Android Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6CPi.png)

But on my real device:
[On Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime VE Duos SM-G531H/DS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUUkY.png)

My list_item_view.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_list_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:text="ExampleList" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center|end"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I would like to do something like this regarding text and buttons:
[List in Mail app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2G4Y.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try it using a `Relative layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_list_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        tools:text="ExampleList" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center|end"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you want it like the last image you've posted then you can use this code, have refined your above code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_list_item_head"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            tools:text="ExampleList" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_list_item_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            tools:text="Example List Description" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|end"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:text="15 m"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|end"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: My main problem is that imageView goes beyond the boundaries of the device screen, although it is displayed normally on the design sheet in Android Studio.
I tried the options with `LinearLayout`,`ConstraintLayout` and your version with `RelativeLayout`. And in all cases, the delete button is outside the screen.

Comment: Thank you for the sample code explaining how the construction of elements in the last image is implemented. I will use this as soon as I deal with the missing delete button :)

Answer (score 0):

When the text length of your TextView will increase then your delete image will overlap with text. So put the vertical guideline.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="72dp"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_list_item"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Hello example" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center|end"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_end="56dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, now I know how to limit the text, but what can I do with the disappearing delete button?

Comment: Is the button still disappearing? because I will recommend Relative, Linealayout etc to you.

Comment: Yes, the button is still disappearing and for some reason, only on real devices.